# Wind Chill Factor

Tags: c++

Trying to write the wind chill factor equation in C++, and am having trouble with my equation and return value.

this is the function where the error comes up.

```
void eqfunction(int temperature, int windspeed){
    int windindex;
    windindex = 35.74 + (0.6215 * temperature);
    windindex = windindex - (35.75 * windspeed^0.16);
    windindex = windindex + ((0.4275 * temperature)*windspeed^0.16);
    return windindex;
}
```

**Edit**: (Ed.) after fixing the function following advice given in answers, new errors crop up:

```
float windChillFactor(float temperature, float windspeed){
    float windindex = 35.74f + 0.6215f * temperature;
    windindex -= 35.75f * std::pow(windspeed, 0.16f);
    windindex += 0.4275f * temperature * std::pow(windspeed, 0.16f);
    return windindex;
}
```

I know there are two things I'm doing wrong I just don't know how to fix them. Obviously its the "^" and my return value. how would I create a square from 0.16 for windspeed?
And how would I create a correct windindex return value?

These are my errors

```
1>c:\users\ryan\desktop\final.cpp\final.cpp\final project.cpp(18):
  warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float',
  possible loss of data
1>c:\users\ryan\desktop\final.cpp\final.cpp\final project.cpp(18):
  warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float',
  possible loss of data
1>c:\users\ryan\desktop\final.cpp\final.cpp\final project.cpp(18):
  error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'int'
1>          Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
1>c:\users\ryan\desktop\final.cpp\final.cpp\final project.cpp(22):
  error C2556: 'float eqfunction(float,float)' : overloaded function differs
  only by return type from 'void eqfunction(float,float)'
1>          c:\users\ryan\desktop\final.cpp\final.cpp\final project.cpp(6) :
            see declaration of 'eqfunction'
1>c:\users\ryan\desktop\final.cpp\final.cpp\final project.cpp(22):
  error C2371: 'eqfunction' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\users\ryan\desktop\final.cpp\final.cpp\final project.cpp(6) :
            see declaration of 'eqfunction'
```

Comment: Well, what is the error?

Comment: error C2556 is stems most likely from you not changing the return value in the declaration of the function. In the declaration you will still have `void eqfunction...` instead of `float eqfunction...` (`windChillFactor`, your error message seem not to match to your code)  The the 2 warnings might stem from you passing the parameters for `eqfunction` as an `int` variable, not a `float`. What values are `temperature` and `windspeed`?

Comment: I added your original function, since the answers are fixing problems with that. Concerning your new errors, it looks like you have two versions of `eqfunction`, differing only in their return value. In C++, you cannot overload by return value, so these two functions are considered to have the same signature, hence the "redefinition" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you haven't included the error message(s) the compiler gives (which you should always do), here are the errors I see:

---

```
void eqfunction(int temperature, int windspeed){
```

- error: Your function returns a value. `void` functions are functions that don't return anything, also known as "procedures" in some other programming languages. Because you want to return real numbers, you may want to use `float` (there are also `double` and `long double`, but in everyday use, `float` is often precise enough).
- design error: Temperature and windspeed are real numbers, so your function should not take `int` but `float`
- It is good practice to give your functions a descriptive name, like you have done with the variable names (unlike in C, in C++ it is more common to *not* use mnenomic functions names)

---

```
    int windindex;
```

- It is good practice to always initialize builtin types
- You are computing the final result using real types, but if you use `int` to store intermediate results, significant information might get lost (when assigning real types to integral types, the fractional part is discarded); so instead of `int`, use `float`

---

```
    windindex = 35.74 + (0.6215 * temperature);
    windindex = windindex - (35.75 * windspeed^0.16);
    windindex = windindex + ((0.4275 * temperature)*windspeed^0.16);
```

- error: the operator `^` is the bitwise exclusive-or operator in C++. The power function is a library function in C++, namely `std::pow(x,y)` from the `cmath` header
- the arithmetic operations `a = a + something`, `a = a - something`, `a = a * something` and `a = a / something` can be simplified to `a += something`, and likewise for the others
- in C++, a literal in the form `1.0` indicates a `double` value, and a literal in the form `1.0f` indicates a `float` value

---

```
    return windindex;
}
```

- that's okay.

---

So, taking those points into account, this might better suit what you want:

```
#include <cmath>

float windChillFactor(float temperature, float windspeed){
    float windindex = 35.74f + 0.6215f * temperature;
    windindex -= 35.75f * std::pow(windspeed, 0.16f);
    windindex += 0.4275f * temperature * std::pow(windspeed, 0.16f);
    return windindex;
}
```

Note that because of operator precedence, `*` and `/` are evaluated before `+` and `-`, so your parentheses weren't needed.

Comment: +1, nice explanation. Some further simplifications can be made by using `+=` and `-=`.

Comment: And as a final touch, change the functions name to something more descriptive than `eqfunction`.

Comment: Good point @user763305, especially at this early point of learning

Comment: @SebastianMach didn't need the answer, but +1 for a good, concise explanation and breakdown

Answer (score 2):

This is the likely error:

```
windspeed^0.16
```

In C++, `^` is the bitwise exclusive or (XOR) operator.

You probably mean to raise `windspeed` to the power of `0.16`, for which you can use `std::pow`:

Besides that, your function should return something other than void. It looks like it should be returning float or double, and `windindex` should not be `int`, but some floating point type. Finally, you can simplify expressions a bit by using `+=` and `-=`:

```
#include <cmath> // for std::pow
double eqfunction(int temperature, int windspeed)
{
    double windindex = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature;
    windindex -= 35.75 * std::pow(windspeed, 0.16);
    windindex += 0.4275 * temperature * std::pow(windspeed, 0.16);
    return windindex;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double eqfunction(int temperature, int windspeed)
{
    double windindex = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature;
    windindex -= 35.75 * std::pow(windspeed, 0.16);
    windindex += 0.4275 * temperature * std::pow(windspeed, 0.16);
    return windindex;
 }
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice. This is just a "Try this"-answer, which may solve the askers specific problem, but not help him in the future, i.e. you are giving fish, instead of teaching to fish.

Comment: @phresnel You are absolutely right, and you have explained everything very well. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. I know the temptation is really high to hack up the correct variant, and we more-experienced programmers may be satisfied by try-this-answers because we suddenly see, word by word, what we did wrong, and then reason about it. But especially for newcomers, some background info can do wonders for the learning experience ... Oh man, I am talking like a teacher ....

Answer (score 0):

```
double eqfunction(int temperature, int windspeed){
    double windindex;
    windindex = 35.74 + (0.6215 * temperature);
    windindex = windindex - (35.75 * pow(windspeed,0.16));
    windindex = windindex + ((0.4275 * temperature)*pow(windspeed,0.16));
    return windindex;
}
```

Comment: But why is `windindex` still an integer, while at the same time you pretend to return `double`?  A lot of significant information might get lost within the course of the function.